# Insufficient free space: XXX extents needed, but only 0 available

Tags: disk, lvm, resize

I'm trying to run this command:

```
lvresize --size +100% --resizefs /dev/mapper/pve-root
```

but geting this error:

```
Insufficient free space: XXX extents needed, but only 0 available
```

Running ProxMox 5.1 and the lvm disk size is only 120GB and want to increase it to use the who dis or just double the size, wasn't successfull in doing it.

Any hellp would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

by run that command you try to re-use the space already used in the VG. Try out with this instead:

```
lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/pve-root
```

P.S. `-l = --size` `-r = --resize` you can use the extended form, if you prefer.

Reference: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/44089

**Update** Source: https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/LVM2#Standard_installation

As you can see in the link of a standard installation on the top of VG "pve" you have different LV:

```
VG  LV  Mountpoint  Note
pve swap        will used as swap partition
pve root    /   Example
pve data    /var/lib/vz/    Proxmox VE < 4.2
pve data        Proxmox VE >= 4.2
```

By check with `lvs` command you will see the size for each LV and the sum of that assigned space are the same amount (or very close) of the VG size.

Once the VG space is all assigned you can't expand a LV until you do not reduce a LV on the same VG or, alternatively add a physical volume to that VG.

So when you see the size of `pve` VG is the following:

```
VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize     VFree 
pve  1   8   0  wz--n- 931.26g   0
```

and is says to you on VG `pve` are present one `Pysical Volume` eight `Logical Volume` the `Volume size` is 931.26g with zero `Volume free` space.

So if you have no free space on the VG, you can not expand LV.

Theoretically if you sum the LV size you should reach the used size of VG.

Comment: that means is already in use all the available space. The VG get some unused space?

Comment: cool, answer removed. back to the issues, the disk is 1tb in size so how can I use all the space? what do you mean by "vg get some unused space"?

Comment: the logical volume are created up to a volum grop, they are also created on physical volume (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)). what the output of vgs?

Comment: Output: root@server:/home/user# vgs
  VG  #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  pve   1   8   0 wz--n- 931.26g    0

Comment: as you can see the VG called pve had no free space to assign anymore (last column) so you cannot expand the LV pve-root. For expand that FS you have to reduce first another LV or add a new PV (physical volume) to the VG pve.

Comment: thanks, but as you can see the disk isn't completely used: 

root@server:/home/user# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1    2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2    4096     528383     524288   256M EFI System
/dev/sda3  528384 1953525134 1952996751 931.3G Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors

the volume in question is only 120GB in size.

Comment: Ok, try now to see how many Logical Volumes are present on the top of Volume Group "pve" by type lvs, I'm sure that will clarify your doubt.

Comment: output: root@server:/home/user# lvs
  LV                        VG  Attr       LSize   Pool Origin        Data%  Meta%  
  data                      pve twi-aotz-- 811.26g                    15.24  7.68
  root                      pve -wi-ao---- 111.79g
  snap_vm-600-disk-1_vzdump pve Vri---tz-k  80.00g data 
  swap                      pve -wi-ao----   8.00g
  vm-500-disk-1             pve Vwi-aotz-- 160.00g data
  vm-600-disk-1             pve Vwi-aotz--  80.00g data
  vm-700-disk-1             pve Vwi-aotz--   8.00g data
  vm-800-disk-1             pve Vwi-a-tz--   8.00g data

Comment: I have update the answer, hope is clear now why you cant expand the LV root

Comment: thanks, what other options do I have to get this resolved?

Comment: The available options are already in the answer, or you reduce the other LV or you add a disk to the VG

Comment: thanks, so I just run the lvresize command on whichever LV I want to reduce?

Comment: Yes, potentially, choose one where have unused space.

Comment: this will probably break my system - https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/resizing-pve-data.30506/